# How to implement Cascade on Delete in laravel One to many relation?

Tags: mysql, laravel

My app is about checklists, in every checklist i have many tabs.
So i have both Checklist and Tab models. The response of checklist looks like this:

```
{
    "checklistId": 52,
    "userId": 17,
    "title": "new titile",
    "created_at": "2021-12-05T12:33:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-12-05T12:33:48.000000Z",
    "tabs": [
        {
            "tabId": 152,
            "checklistId": 52,
            "name": "Default",
            "created_at": "2021-12-05T12:33:48.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-05T12:33:48.000000Z"
        }
    ]
},
```

I want to implement cascade on delete, so when i deleting row from checklist table, all the rows in tabs table which have checklistId like deleting checklist will be deleted too.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints sidenote. This is something that needs to be declared when the foreign key constraint is declared and not on the fly

Answer (score 0):

```
class Checklist extends Eloquent
{
    public function tabs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tabs::class);
    }

    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($checklist) { 
             $checklist ->tabs()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).